# In MVC, how can I update a column data that is related to another table/model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let's say I have these two as examples:

```
public class Cat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set }
    public CatColor Color { get; set; } // I'd like to change this value
}

public class CatColor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set }
}
```

I have a form that prompts for Cat values, Id (auto generated), Name, Color. I have no issues updating/creating the Name but the Color value doesn't change at all.

In the database CatColor can be assigned to many Cats. This should be a simple task but I've been staring at it for a while now.

In my controller I have something like this:

```
   public ActionResult SaveCat(Cat objCat)
   {
        Cat oc = db.Cat.Include(d => d.CatColor).ToList().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == objCat.Id);
        oc.Name = objCat.Name;
        // oc.CatColor.Color = objCat.Color ???
        ...
        db.SaveChanges();
        return ..
   }
```

Just wondering how I could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the ForeignKey data annotation

```
public class Cat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ColorId")]
    public CatColor Color { get; set; } 
}
```

you can do it like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveCat(Cat objCat)
{
        Cat oc = db.Cat.Include(d => d.CatColor).ToList().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == objCat.Id);
     oc.Name = objCat.Name;
     oc.CatColor.ColorId = objCat.ColorId
     ...
     db.SaveChanges();
     return ..
}
```

Note: the objCat.ColorId can be populated pretty easily if in your view you have a dropdown with all the possible CatColors

**EDIT**

I've placed the foreign key data annotation in the wrong property... my bad.